# How to delete direct message from bot that already sent?

Tags: discord.py

Hi I recently tested the DM user command in Discord.py rewrite version and forgot to use the **delete_after** parameter now my DM is filled with Bot message spam how do I make my bot to delete it's own message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do:

```
send = await ctx.send("test message")
```

and later, to delete the message:

```
await send.delete()
```

This would obviously change because you're doing a DM and not a direct message to a server, but the logic to delete said message is the same.